# Is SAT score a count variable?

Tags: count-data, continuous-data

It can't be continuous because you can't get a decimal [SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT) score, right?

Comment: This is an international list with many fields represented. I don't think you can assume that all readers know what SAT scores are.  But the answer can be as subtle as you want. It may be a convention to report such scores rounded, and for all I know a marking scheme makes integer results inevitable. But in practice with hundreds of possible values, SAT will behave like many continuous variables  (Never took a SAT test in my life...) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SAT score is discrete, but it is not a count. Not all discrete variables need to be counts. SAT score is an interval variable. Typically, SAT score is treated as a continuous variable in regression models.

Comment: I like the flavour of this, but how far is the SAT score a weighted count of correct answers? (Please note my comment on the question.)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I guess at a large enough sample size it would be considered continuous. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, what linear regression model would you use to model SAT score against something like, average candidate weight and percentage of candidates with asthma?

Comment: New question, new thread, please.

Comment: @NickCox my understanding is that the SAT score is an item response theory factor score estimate rescaled to range between 200 and 800 with a certain mean and standard deviation and rounded to integers. I believe it's not simply how many answers but which answers were got correct.

Comment: Sounds like a weighted count then....

Answer (score 0):

First, for those who don't know, the SAT is a common test in American high schools and is used in college admissions. Scores are integers ranging from 0 to 800.

Now, to the meat of the question: SAT scores aren't really counts - they are computed from the number of right and wrong answers, but the computation is not simply a count. But even if it were a count, it would be treated as continuous for nearly all purposes because 800 levels is simply too much to deal with.

And, to get pedantic, even a variable like weight is a count - number of quarks or whatever - but it's silly to treat it that way.

Comment: Using some authoritative references would help you give a more accurate answer. E.g., "To calculate section scores, we first compute the student’s raw score—the number of questions correctly answered—for each section. Nothing is deducted for incorrect answers or for unanswered questions. Next, we convert each of the raw section scores to a scaled score of 200 to 800." See https://collegereadiness.collegeboard.org/sat/scores/understanding-scores .